# Modify toggle checkbox script in check uncheck all checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have the following script that works

```
    function toggle_checkboxes(id) {
        if (!document.getElementById) {
            return;
        }
        if (!document.getElementsByTagName) {
            return;
        }
        var inputs = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
            if (inputs[x].type == 'checkbox') { 
                inputs[x].checked = !inputs[x].checked;
            }
        }
    }
```

The script does what it says: Toggle the checkbox status. I to modify existing script to check / uncheck all check boxes. How can I do that?

I tried with

```
inputs[x].checked = false;
inputs[x].removeAttr('checked');
```

but it didn't work. Anyone?

Comment: no jquery here.. for jquery use `.prop()`

Comment: My mistake, I will edit the tags now.

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want script to check if there any checked checkboxes to uncheck them.

Comment: I replaced `!inputs[x].checked` with false just like you said you tried and it unchecked all boxes. What is not working?

Comment: Try to have one checkbox checked. and then click the button. The checked will become unchecked and the others will become checked.

Comment: @user2417624 Are you sure you replaced `!inputs[x].checked` with `false` like you said? I did and the function unchecks all boxes. What you are describing is what the function does without changing it. Are you sure the code you are writing is what is actually being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost close. You just need to do:

```
inputs[x].removeAttribute('checked');
```

The function `removeAttr()` is the equivalent function used in jQuery. And moreover you don't need the extra parameter `id`.

```js
function toggle_checkboxes(id) {
  var inputs = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
    if (inputs[x].type == 'checkbox') {
      inputs[x].checked = !inputs[x].checked;
    }
  }
}
function uncheck_checkboxes(id) {
  var inputs = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
    if (inputs[x].type == 'checkbox') {
      inputs[x].checked = false;
    }
  }
}
function check_checkboxes(id) {
  var inputs = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
    if (inputs[x].type == 'checkbox') {
      inputs[x].checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="chks">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="" /> Check 1</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="" checked /> Check 2</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="" /> Check 3</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="" checked /> Check 4</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="" /> Check 5</label>
  <br>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Toggle" onclick='toggle_checkboxes("chks");' />
<input type="button" value="Uncheck All" onclick='uncheck_checkboxes("chks");' />
<input type="button" value="check All" onclick='check_checkboxes("chks");' />
```

Comment: Does not work, script continues the same behaviour. If there are checked checkboxes, uncheck those and then check the unchecked ones. I want to uncheck all checkboxes and then to check them all.